# How to make a helper method for PSQL to INSERT values into DB

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

I'm trying to build in my NodeJS API a helper for the queries, so I will no need to write always or almost always the same queries just changing like the name of the table, values, and params.
I'm using PG without an ORM as an exercise about SQL queries.
What I'm trying to do is to build a universal INSERT helper like the following one

```
insertOne(table, values, params) {
        const arr1 = [...values];
        const arr2 = [...params];
        return query(`INSERT INTO ${table}
                        (${arr1})
                        VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
                        RETURNING*`, [arr2]);
    }
```

I tried to do in this way but getting the error:

```
"bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 6"
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to insert into the DB calling when I need this method to replace the nex query I'm using now:

```
async createOne(req, res) {
        console.log({ ...req.body });
        try {
            const product = await query(
                `INSERT INTO products
                    (productname, description, brand, price, category, imageurl)
                VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
                RETURNING*`,
                [
                    req.body.productname,
                    req.body.description,
                    req.body.brand,
                    req.body.price,
                    req.body.category,
                    req.body.imageurl
                ]
            );
            res.json({ msg: "Product added", data: product.rows });
        } catch (err) {
            return res.json({ msg: "POST Something went wrong!", err: err });
        }
    }
```

I would like to be able to replace what above with the helper passing the values and params as arguments when I call the method. 
But I stuck and need help to make it work.

[EDIT]
Adding the helper as required by comment the entire file:

```
const { query } = require("../db/dbConnect");

const Queries = {
    findAll(table) {
        return query(`SELECT * FROM ${table}`);
    },

    findOne(table, id, params) {
        return query(`SELECT * FROM ${table} where ${id} = $1`, [params]);
    },

    insertOne(table, values, params) {
        const arr1 = [...values];
        const arr2 = [params];
        return query(
            `INSERT INTO ${table}
                        (${arr1})
                        VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
                        RETURNING*`, [arr2]
        );
    }
};

module.exports = { Queries };
```

And inserOne call

```
async createOne(req, res) {
    console.log({ ...req.body });
    try {
        const product = await Queries.insertOne(
            "products",
            [
                "productname",
                "description",
                "brand",
                "price",
                "category",
                "imageurl"
            ],
            [
                req.body.productname,
                req.body.description,
                req.body.brand,
                req.body.price,
                req.body.category,
                req.body.imageurl
            ]
        );
        res.json({ msg: "Product added", data: product.rows });
    } catch (err) {
        return res.json({ msg: "POST Something went wrong!", err: err });
    }
},
```

Comment: Use `arr2` instead of `[arr2]`

Comment: Not working that as in the SQL I have to pass this query as per documentation
`INSERT INTO table (colums) values(...), [params]`

Comment: The documentation says you need to pass an array, and `arr2` is such an array. You should not pass an array of arrays.

Comment: If you know the solution why don't you post an answer like that is difficult to understand what you have in mind. In SQL the parameters assigned to $1 $n need to be inside the square brackets without the command in SQL is not accepted so the squrse brraktets there need to be.

Comment: I think you understood exactly what I meant, but you keep insisting that the "square brackets" are necessary. They're not, it has nothing to do with SQL. The `query` function expects an array of values as its second parameters, you can do that by either constructing an array literal, or by simply passing an array.

Comment: By the way with or without square brackets is not working I tried so if you have a solution I can try more please post an answer

Comment: If it doesn't work without parenthesis, can you please [edit] your question to include the call to `insertOne`?

Comment: I edited please check my entire Queries helper the other ore running only the last one no

Comment: No, not the helper definition. Please show the *call* to the helper function that doesn't work, where you are passing values for `tables`, `values` and `params`.

Comment: Already did it I forgot to paste before now is there

Comment: In the updated code, you also broke `const arr2 = [...params];` to become `const arr2 = [params];`. You don't need any of this, you should directly pass the `params` to `query`. (Btw, the `values` parameter really should be called `columns`)

Comment: So I already did in many different ways also as you suggested no one worked for me actually